# Replace with zeros columns using all combinations in matlab

Tags: loops, matlab, combinations

I'm trying to loop through all the combinations of columns replacing with zeros.

My code replaces one column of zeros each time, i.e `nchoosek(5, 1)` and I generated `nchoosek(5, 5)` but I need the rest of the combinations, that is:

```
nchoosek(5, 2);
nchoosek(5, 3);
nchoosek(5, 4);
```

My code so far looks like this, where `prodordered` is a numeric `24x5`:

```
nplants=5
nhours=24

for j= 1:nplants,
    outage = ones(nhours,nplants);
    outage(:,j) = zeros(nhours,1);
    prodout = outage.*prodordered;
    meritorder = prodout(:,1);
   
end
```

I tried

```
for j= 1:nchoosek(1:nplants,2),
    outage = ones(nhours,nplants);
    outage(:,j) = zeros(nhours,1);
end
```

But I get just one result which is substituting the first column with zeros, how can I do all combinations?

Comment: So in your example you would need 32 different `outage` matrices with 1 column of zeros, then 2 columns, so on, up to all the 32 possibilities? Do you need them in any specified order, such as first all combinations with 1 column of zeros, then 2 columns of zeros etc, or is order irrelevant? Also, are you only using `outage` to make the corresponding columns of `prodordered` equal to 0? In other words, can you dispose of `outage` and directly set the columns of `prodorder` to 0 in `prodout`?

Comment: I need 31 combinations `nchoosek(5, 1)=5`;`nchoosek(5, 2)=10`;`nchoosek(5, 3)=10`,`nchoosek(5, 4)=5`;`nchoosek(5, 5)=1`. Yes, the order will help; first, the combination of four columns being zero, then the combination of 3 columns being zero, etc. I can't index in `prodorder` because I'm using `prodorder` further in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you need:

```
nplants = 5;
nhours = 24;
for k = nplants:-1:1 % for each number of columns to be zeroed out
    for comb = fliplr(nchoosek(1:nplants, k).') % for each set of k columns
        outage = ones(nhours, nplants); % initiallize to ones
        outage(:, comb) = 0; % make columns zero
        % Do stuff with outage...
    end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to not include the combination `nchoosek(5, 5)=1` and invert the order of combinations? The first combination is `0,0,0,0,5`; can it be `1,0,0,0,0`? And similar for all other combinations?

Comment: @Lilia Please see now

Comment: To include or exclude combinations, modify the `for k=...` line. I'm not sure which one you want to exclude: the one with all zeros, or withh nonzeros?

Comment: exclude the one with nonzeros